# Incompatible type in Objective C Iphone SDK 4.0

Tags: objective-c, ios4

//  CStroke.h
    #import

```
@interface CStroke : NSObject {
    CGFloat *startX;
    CGFloat *startY;
    CGFloat *endX;
    CGFloat *endY;
    BOOL *state;
}
@property CGFloat *startX;
@property CGFloat *startY;
@property CGFloat *endX;
@property CGFloat *endY;
@property BOOL *state;
-(void)setStroke: (CGFloat *)newStartX andStartY:(CGFloat *)newStartY andEndX:(CGFloat *)newEndX andEndY:(CGFloat *)newEndY;
@end
```

After set up CStroke class, I am going to use it in ViewController to draw something out using CGFloat

```
CGFloat *startX = (CGFloat *)[[self retrieveStartCoordinateOfStroke:k whichKindOfCoorXOrY:@"X"] integerValue];
        CGFloat *startY = (CGFloat *)[[self retrieveStartCoordinateOfStroke:k whichKindOfCoorXOrY:@"Y"] integerValue];
        CGFloat *endX = (CGFloat *)[[self retrieveEndCoordinateOfStroke:k whichKindOfCoordXOrY:@"X"] integerValue];
        CGFloat *endY = (CGFloat *)[[self retrieveEndCoordinateOfStroke:k whichKindOfCoordXOrY:@"Y"] integerValue];
        CStroke *stroke = [[CStroke alloc] init];
        [stroke setStroke:startX andStartY:startY andEndX:endX andEndY:endY];
```

This is where I got error...I can't figure out what happened...are they both CGFloat type...Any answer for this?
The error is incompatible type for argument 2 of 'CGContextAddLineToPoint' and incompatible type for argument 2 of 'CGContextMoveToPoint'

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), myStroke.startX, myStroke.startY);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [myStroke endX], [myStroke endY]);
```

Comment: can you improve your title?  Also, post the error that you're getting, 'got error of incompatible type' doesn't help much.

Comment: done! Though I am not sure where this error come from 'cuz I only start ObjC a week ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you're making your coordinates, pointers to `CGFloat` and not `CGFloat` types. They are not object types. `CGfloat` is **currently, do not rely on this in the future** just a type alias to `float`, and the functions you're passing to eventually, expect the scalar values, not pointers.

On a secondary note, getting the current graphics context is not a cheap operation. Do it once. That is, change your code to look something like this:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Now pass in context where you would normally pass in UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
```

Comment: So should I modify my CStroke class or something else?

Comment: Otherwise how do I change my pointers into normal scalar values...and thx for the context recommendation...it seriously helped :)

Comment: You don't. You can ask the pointer for the thing it points to, this is done by dereferencing the pointer. However, in your case, that will almost certainly cause your application to crash, since you just have the wrong types from the get-go. Best case, you'd get back garbage. I strongly recommend you pick up a book on C. Objective-C is merely a superset of C—That is, everything that applies in C, also applies to Objective-C. Pay particular attention to pointers, how they work and why they're useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I really understand what you are trying to do, but I don't really think you really meant to use pointers to floats...
try using just float and not pointers:

```
//CGFloat *startX; no need for it to be a pointer
CGFloat startX; // just a regular CGFloat is enough
//change all your variables to be CGFloats and not pointers to CGFloats
```

Comment: Oh great...I fixed it...btw I seriously don't understand why do we have to set pointers anyway...

Comment: I mean the purpose of pointers really...sry because I come from java background ... rawr